# javascript for loop does not work

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm creating a site and i needed to do some js. I'm not that good with it but tought i would figer it out. Not. I created a for loop but it does not run.

```
function order(user,product){
    var index;
    for(var i = 0; i<users.lenght; i++){
        if(user == users[i]){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    var budget = budgets[index];
    alert(budget);
}
```

the creation of the users and budgets arrays are done with php and after checking with alert() it was how it should be.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: how user and user[i] can be equal? Cause your going to compare a array with a string, or number or a boolean. This will never pass your if statement.

Comment: please add `users` and `budgets` as well. and btw, why is the same `index` for `users` and `budgets`? and what are you doing with `product`?

Answer (score 2):

`lenght` is spelt `length`. The misspelt property does not exist, so it `undefined`, which is equivalent to `0`.

Comment: That should rather be a comment.

Comment: @Gothdo - It correctly answered the question, therefore it is an answer.